# Redirected to captcha when accessing google translate

Tags: php, google-translate

I'm trying to retrieving data from Google Translate for my website.  I use this sample for retrieving data from Google Translate:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=find&hl=en&sl=en&tl=fr
```

but now it's redirecting me to:

```
http://ipv4.google.com/sorry
```

This has been working fine for me for the last two years, but the issue appeared last night. What is causing this, and what can I do about it?

Comment: From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs): "Google Translate API is available as a paid service."  Are you paying for these translations?

Comment: He said it used to work fine for him, so he must be paying for these translations.

Comment: @Army-L Or he was scraping and they've detected it.

Comment: The new thing here is Google's implementation of captcha codes on this service. Text and audio snippets used to be freely downloadable.

Comment: The service is still free, but only accessible via a browser, and you have to prove you are a human via captcha. My old command-line tool to download audio no longer works, so now I have a lot of typing every time I want to get the audio :(.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the parameters in your url here is another link that should work:
https://translate.google.co.uk/#en/fr/find

The setup seems to be
https://translate.google.co.uk/#{original language}/{translate to language}/{text to translate}

However I have to point out that scraping google translate is against the TOS, they do have an api here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs

Unfortunately this costs roughly $2 per one hundred thousand characters translated.

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative that may be more appropriate for you is the [Google Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/). Follow the instructions to get a code snippet to add to your website to embed a translator tool.

Comment: Now it is not working anymore!!!!!  **We no longer provide new access to Google Translate's Website Translator. This change does not affect existing use of the Website Translator.

We encourage users looking to translate webpages to use browsers that support translation natively.**